# HTTP Basic Authentication header

Tags: android, http-headers, httpurlconnection

I need to create an class which searches some routes and timetables of Florianópolis's public transportation

Here are the specs:

The REST APIs listed below require authentication, 
all the requests must include a HTTP Basic Authentication header.

username = "WKD4N7YMA1uiM8V"

password = "DtdTtzMLQlA0hk2C1Yi5pLyVIlAQ68"

All the HTTP requests must also include this custom header: "X-AppGlu-Environment: staging".

should query this endpoint to get the results:

POST https://api.appglu.com/v1/queries/findRoutesByStopName/run

Body:
{
"params": {
"stopName": "%lauro linhares%"
}
}

Some streets for testing: [Delminda Silveira, Mauro Ramos, Governador Irineu Bornhausen, Deputado Antônio Edu Vieira].

So here is my code:

```
String targetURL = "http://192.168.1.1";
String username = "WKD4N7YMA1uiM8V";
String password = "DtdTtzMLQlA0hk2C1Yi5pLyVIlAQ68";

URL url = new URL(targetURL);
 HttpURLConnection connection;
connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

BASE64Encoder enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
```

I honestly don't know what to do next. I perfer to use httpurlconnection rather than that apache stuff..

Comment: Your String(s) appear to be Base64 already.

Answer (score 0):

You should add headers to your requests. It will be something like:

```
mHttpPost.addHeader("username", "WKD4N7YMA1uiM8V");
mHttpPost.addHeader("password", "DtdTtzMLQlA0hk2C1Yi5pLyVIlAQ68");
mHttpPost.addHeader("X-AppGlu-Environment", "staging");
```

where `mHttpPost` is your `HttpPost` variable.

You can start by reading [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) and [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheHttpClient/article.html) to get familiar with sending Http requests

Comment: with apologies, i have no idea what you are talking about. I will need baby steps because i am totally new to this.

Comment: httpost? i thought that stuff was deprecated. rather we should be using httpurlconnection